# Make Chromium and sites dark

Tags: chromium

I am trying to make all of the white space on most sites black or dark and the text white. I tried a Chrome extension called [Hacker Vision](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hacker-vision/fommidcneendjonelhhhkmoekeicedej?hl=en-US). It did not work. If anyone knows another way it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I haven't tried "Hacker Vision" but in what way did it not work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [High Contrast extension from Google](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/high-contrast/djcfdncoelnlbldjfhinnjlhdjlikmph?hl=en-US) claims to do what you want in part:

> High Contrast lets you browse the web with your choice of several high-contrast color filters designed to make it easier to read text.
>
> When you install this extension, all pages are "inverted", so **black becomes white** and white becomes black. Press the "browser action" icon in the toolbar to toggle it on and off, or customize your settings on a per-site basis. Use a convenient keyboard shortcut to quickly change your settings while your browse.
>
> Other extensions try to change the default colors, but this ends up breaking many popular websites. Only this extension applies filters to your page that invert almost everything - the only exception is photos, which are left alone.
>
> Also note that the Chrome web store and other built-in pages like the New Tab page and Settings pages are unaffected - extensions like this one are not allowed to modify them, by design.

(text not **Bold** in the original)

However, there's is the **black becomes white** aspect to deal with.

Another, do-it-yourself extension is [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe/details?hl=en-US):

> Restyle the web with Stylish, a user styles manager. Stylish lets you easily install themes and skins for Google, Facebook,…
>
> User styles are themes for web sites. User styles empower your browsing experience by letting you customize web sites. Take out irrelevant content, change colors, or completely redesign the entire site.

You may be able to use that extension successfully, depending on your competence in CSS or good luck in finding dark "styles" [here](http://userstyles.org/). An example of a decent dark style is [NightShift - eye care](http://userstyles.org/styles/18192/nightshift-eye-care).

There's also an active help forum for Stylish [here](http://forum.userstyles.org/).

I prefer the Stylish extension over High Contrast. Stylish gives me more "control" over the page than does High Contrast. The forum is pretty helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the developers settings in your Chromium Browser (chrome://flags) and from there search and enable "Force Dark Mode for Web Contents".